# zf2 ModuleManager config merge - remove key

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm not sure if this is possible, but...

The zf2 ModuleManager will merge all the config arrays for modules in order, then merge any user defined config arrays. So, if `$config1` is merged with `$config2` you get `$merged`.

```
$config1 = [
   'key1' => 1,
   'key2' => 2,
   'key3' => 3
]

$config2 = [
    'key1' => 'different',
    'key4' => 4
]

$merged = [
    'key1' => 'different',
    'key2' => 2
    'key3' => 3
    'key4' => 4
]
```

That's great, and works for most cases. However, what if I want to remove a key? If I have `$config1` as above, and want to create this alternate `$merged` below, then what should the value of `$config2` be (notice that `key2` is removed)?

```
$merged = [
    'key1' => 'different',
    'key3' => 3
    'key4' => 4
]
```

Comment: @Sam take eg ZfcUser where you only want the classes but not the route registered. It's fairly difficult to unregister things at this moment. The feature is planned afaik superdweebie, but it does not exists yet. The configuration knows which part comes from what module, so you might check all those parts, unregister something and then rebuild the configuration. It should work, but there is no simple api for it yet.

Comment: Is it much of a difference if i use one line to `un-register` something, or if i use a line to `nullify` a configuration? If i don't want ZfcUsers routes to be registered, i override them with a `null` value. Or would that not work? `'routes' => array('zfcuser' => null)`

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure if override with `null` will work for routes, it depends on how the route factory handles nulls. The point is, it would be very nice to unregister so that the what the factory never sees a null it needs to handle.

Comment: @JurianSluiman pity it's not possible. Good that it's a planned feature. Do you know if anyone is working on it, or is there a RFC or PR active? (If there isn't, I might have a go).  I'm thinking a special value should be defined, like `__unregister__` which the ModuleManager can look for. If the MM see's the value, it removes the key.

Comment: @superdweebie overriding with `null` will afaik not work since it is then skipped for the recursive merging. If you would like to work on this feature, check for Evan (EvanDotPro on irc) or Matthew (weierophinney on irc). IRC is #zftalk.dev on freenode iirc. There you can get more help about development of zf2.

Comment: @JurianSluiman I've opened a PR. The changes needed to make this work were quite small. https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/3504

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but perhaps you could create a listener for the `loadModules.post` event. Off the top of my head, I don't remember if the modules' configs have been merged when this event is triggered, but I think so - it makes the most sense. Wouldn't it then be possible to simply use `unset()` on keys in the merged config in your listener? Again, I am not sure if this would work, but perhaps it is worth considering. Any input on this approach?

Comment: @andy124, your suggestion would work, but clearly it requires code outside `config.php`, which I was hoping to avoid. I have a PR against zf2 that might be accepted. For now overriding with `null` is the closest simple option. And, @DASPRiD says he's working on a solution to route overriding.

Comment: @superdweebie Yes, that's true. I just read here that it was not _possible_, so I thought I would throw it out there. Thanks for the PR. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now fixed in zf2 master. Likely to be in zf2 2.3. See this great tutorial for how it's done (see MERGE_CONFIG event)

https://github.com/weierophinney/zf2-documentation/blob/71aac39e9ae78eaca3739458c5a2ccf15f4cdb2c/docs/languages/en/tutorials/config.advanced.rst

BTW at the time of writing this tutorial was still just a PR, and not in the official docs yet.

Comment: See http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorials/config.advanced.html#manipulating-merged-configuration

Answer (score 2):

Let take any module.php for purpose (you can make it specific according to your needs).

try this below code

```
pulbic function init(){

$events = StaticEventManager::getInstance();

$events->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', array(
    $this,
    'removeMyKey'
    ), 110);
}
public function removeMyKey($mvcEvent){
    $sl = $mvcEvent->getTarget()->getServiceLocator();
    $config = $sl->get('Config');
    unset($config['key2']);
    $sl->set('Config',$config);
    return $sl;
}
```

Hope this helps to remove the key. Make alteration as required.

Comment: This will remove a key, but only after all configs are merged. What is needed is the ability to remove keys during merge. See https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3823 for the latest discussion. As of writing, the issue is still unresolved.